# Accessing arguments within a callback (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, closures

I'm trying to write a "debounce" function, and I'm stuck in one segment of the code. In the code below, I pass a callback into `addEventListener` and I wrap it in a `debounce` function.

This function will have more functionality later, but for now, I just want it to return a function, that will set a timeout for `delay` milliseconds and then call the original function with the argument (in this case `e`).

My problem is on the line in the `debounce` function that says `callback("original-args")`. I would like to replace "original-args" with the actual argument that was passed into the callback. How do I get access to that argument?

```js
  button.addEventListener("click", debounce(e => {
    let elem = document.createElement("P"); 
    elem.textContent = "Clicked";
    container.appendChild(elem);
  }, 2000))

  function debounce(callback, delay) {
    return function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        callback("original-args")
      }, delay)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
button.addEventListener(
  "click",
  debounce(
    (e) => {
      let elem = document.createElement("P");
      elem.textContent = "Clicked";
      container.appendChild(elem);
    },
    2000
  )
);

function debounce(callback, delay) {
  return function (...args) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

So you can pass the `...args` down to your debounced function. The `...args` is a spread operator that means `take any number of arguments and store them inside the variable args`.